# Загрузка памяти RemoteObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Заметил на слабом ПК проблему с производительностью при использовании RemoteObjectManager в Google Chrome.

1. Чем больше меток загрузилось, тем больше начинает всё тормозить. А меток у меня счёт на тысячи, но тормоза начинаются уже на сотнях.

Я пробовал очищать менеджер геообъектов для эксперимента и удалять сам менеджер с карты, но это не помогает.

```
remoteObjectManager.objects.removeAll();
myMap.geoObjects.remove(remoteObjectManager);
```

Пробовал в качестве эксперимента remoteObjectManager.reloadData(), думал, он очищает память перед запросом новых данных, но нет.

На ПК с 8 ГБ оперативной памяти проблем никаких не было.

2. Если перезагрузить полностью страницу, то даже в этом случае проблема остаётся - жутко тормозит карта. Но если закрыть вкладку и открыть эту же карту в новой (не дублировать, а именно открыть в новой вкладке) - там всё будет уже хорошо, пока не начнёшь загружать много меток.

Я сделал вывод, что объекты продолжают висеть в памяти до закрытия вкладки. И вот тут резонный вопрос: что делать?

Самое интересное, что на этом же ПК в IE 11 такой проблемы нет - сколько бы меток не загрузилось, если их удалить с карты или при изменении параметров карты запросить новые данные через reloadData() - заметно ускоряется перемещение по карте.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полный код, на котором можно наблюдать тормоза и версию Chrome.

Comment: Пришлите пожалуйста ссылку на страницу, где можно воспроизвести проблему или пришлите код.

Comment: Извините, что не отвечал так долго. Проблема со временем решилась. Не знаю, с чем это связано, то ли с выходом новых версий API, то ли просто я сильно переработал свой код.